# How can I cache external scripts in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, external-script

To improve the performance on my website I'm thinking about caching some of the external scripts which have long loading time.

Does it make sense to cache this scripts in aws and request them from there instead of the external ones or is it not worth the effort?

And what would be the best way to do this? I'd like to save this scripts for maybe a day and then refresh them.

Comment: CloudFront - just try routing the traffic through cloudfront and see how much the loading times improve and then decide if that is worth it.

Comment: @luk2302 most likely means CloudFront.

Comment: @Maurice of course, seems my brain is still in bed.

Comment: @luk2302 and this will also cache external javascript files?

Comment: Instead of `https://external.domain/file.js` create a cloudfront distribution that redirects to `https://external.domain` and then send your request for an external file to `https://your-distribution.cloufront.com/file.js` (e.g. following [this link](https://atenea.marfeel.com/atn/marfeel-press/systems-requirements/set-up-a-reverse-proxy-configuration/create-a-reverse-proxy-and-cache-using-amazon-cloudfront))